# Getting Location in Android for different activities

Tags: android, gps

I am developing an app which uses GPS in many Activities.
At first I thought of implementing the LocationListener in each Activity. However I wonder if is possible a better approach to the problem by having a service with the GPS. What do you think is the right path to follow?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a base activity class that implements the [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) interface, and have all your location-aware activities subclass this base activity. Since only only one activity is active and in the foreground at a time, there's no waste of resources here. (Assuming you register in onResume, and call removeUpdates in onPause for instance)

Comment: And what is the diference with implement the locationListener in each activity, instead of extend each class?

Comment: Implementing the same code instead of reusing code is bad practice in terms of object oriented programming. It makes your code bigger, and harder to maintain. If you want in the future to change your location-specific code, you'd have to change in several locations, instead of just one (The base class)

Comment: @Lior if I use a high value for the ```minTime``` parameter (interval for updates in milliseconds), I don't need to stop the updates in each activity? I have to call a WS and update the location each 30 minutes (I don't need the location in each activity, just want to have a service performing requests).